# Inline image list not aligning with text, breaks structure

Tags: html, css

So I signed up here because I have something that drives me crazy. I am sure the answer is pretty straight and simple, but I just can see it...

I want to make a small gallery for an article, showing screenshots from different video games. The problem: The list wont align correctly with the text within the content `div`. No matter what I do. `text-align: left` just gets it to exactly this position, `center` and `right` work. It is like it is aligning on the edge of a `div`, but there is none. Putting it within the needed `<p>` tags destroys the text like seen in the picture. Keeping it out of the `<p>` tags keeps the text like it should be, but the list is exactly at the same place. I tried `inline-block`, `inline`, `position: absolute` etc, but nothing seems to work. I already tried searching the other `div`s for problems, but I just can't find anything. [Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF7fA.png).

This is the css:

```
.gallerie {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.gallerie ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.gallerie li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Can't somehow show the HTML part here, but it's just a simple `ul` `li` list with images. The whole thing is simple, but something just doesn't.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

So as I can't get the thing with the code right, here is the direct linkt to the page with that problem: [Link to the Problem](http://vfx-world.com/evolution-of-video-game-graphics.php)

I hope this is allowed here. Thank you to the admin for editing, I am new here, and really not used to it. Thank you very much.

So guys, in short:

*wanted to add the pictures here, can't post more than two links*

Edit:
Funny thing, it works when I put the ul li outside of the article tag. So I would have a workaround.

Edit: The problem seems to be within the article tag. I have both, right and left margin in there. But when I make it to margin 0px, the whole text moves left (thats why I have a margin of 20px there). I guess the problem will be a second unneeded margin.

Edit: I fixed this by taking away the margin-left: 20px; out of the article tag, and added the value to the p tag for that class instead. Works. I don't really know what the error was, but it seems fine now. Thank you all for your help.

Last Edit: You can see the working example when you refresh the link to the site. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can put big blocks of code in by indenting it with four spaces.  Check the edit I just made for an example.

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: Welcome to SO, Daniel. Please have a look at my answer below to see if it works for you.

Comment: Your issue is `.gallerie ul` which is looking for a `ul` element that is a child of an element with the `.gallerie` class. Change the `.gallerie ul` to `.gallerie` as stated in @Mr.Meeseeks answer.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help. I updated the post, the problem seems to be the article tag and a margin value somewhere else. Guess I'll just need to search.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is [`css padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/padding)

`<ul>` tags have default padding. If you set `padding: 0;` then the spacing should disappear.

I would say set `text-align: center;` and `padding: 0;` for the `.gallerie` class

Is this what you want?

[image: Image 1]

Corresponding css for `.gallerie`

[image: Image 2]

Padding Example:

```css
.padded {
  padding: 10px;
  background: red;
}

p {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="padded">
  <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't help I'm afraid. But thank you. I'll delete the padding nonetheless. Putting the list within extra <code>div</code> didn't help too,

Comment: You will have to be more precise as to what you want exactly. I've added some images to my answer. Please take a look.

Comment: Sure, sorry, this is what I get: http://vfx-world.com/wip/htmlproblem2.png this is what i want: http://vfx-world.com/wip/htmlproblem3.png it just doesn't want to align with the text, no matter what I do. The other image was just an example that a simple img tag works perfectly fine, the list does not. Sorry I just don't get that forum software. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link to the page where the issue lies. Just give the `.gallerie` class `padding:0;` and a `margin-left:15px;` (to achieve uniform indentation).

It appears from the page that you may be attempting to wrap the `<ul>` in a `<p>`, which is not valid HTML.

Comment: @Daniel have you found a solution to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `padding-left: 20px` to the `<ul>` and wrap the text underneath in a `<p>`